# Youtube.com doesn't work on any browsers, throws multiple kinds of errors my way

Tags: networking, google-chrome, ssl, youtube

I use mainly Chrome, but I checked out other browsers (like Edge) and it didn't work on them either.

At first I couldn't connect to YouTube, because:

> the connection was not private" (NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID)

Rightfully so, because for some reason when I visit YouTube it uses a certificate assigned to "*.radiotime.com". I've never even visited radiotime.com before so I have no idea what could cause this.

I deleted all of my cookies and all of the other temporary files in Chrome (and in 'Internet Settings') and after that I started getting different kinds of errors. Basically it was alternating from `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` to `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. And this still only happens on YouTube.com!

This couldn't be some kind of attack either, because I'm on my home wired network.

After that I messed around a bit more, deleted cookies again etc. and then it just started working...for a few seconds and then it went back to the certificate error. After that a few minutes went by and I tried more things until again it miraculously started working, but this time for about an hour or so and then it went back.

I **am** using one of those SmartDNS services to unblock content from other regions (Unblock-Us.com), but it couldn't be related to that, because I've set it up on my router (so it's enabled for all of my devices) and YouTube works just fine on any other device.

So what's wrong and what can I do?

Comment: My first three thoughts are some sort of malware on that computer, you (or someone or something else) have youtube.com redirected to some other IP, or the OS is screwed up somehow and needs to be reinstalled. Also, what happens if you disable the SmartDNS service?

Comment: Chrome and Edge both use the operating system's certificate store.  So if you are getting a certificate claimed to be signed by anyone except Google then you need to determine the reason for that is

Comment: I switched back to the default DNS servers and it still doesn't work. I'm not really an expert on SSL, but isn't the invalid certificate coming from the "youtube server"? As in, the certificate isn't stored anywhere on my PC, it gets sent over when I visit YT. I know that the actual real YouTube isn't sending me an invalid certificate since it works for everyone else, but my point is that it isn't a problem with my certificate store, right? And I don't know what could be the problem then. I will scan my PC with Malwarebytes, tho.

Comment: No malware on my PC according to Malwarebytes

Comment: @Fabis Check your system date, if by any chance is set to the past. Try also in Chrome Incognito mode. Also check your `hosts` file.

Comment: @Fabis Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Check your proxy settings.

Comment: be aware that flash may store cookies and data separately from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't any malware now, there may have been some in the past. Make sure your dns server on your pc is set to automatic and there isn't anything other than the localhost line in your HOSTS file.

Comment: Already checked the hosts file before - it is empty. And yea everything is set to automatic for the connection - it gets everything from the router with DHCP. I really think this has something to do with certificates not malware or some kind of redirect.

Comment: I don't know what it could be, but i checked on radio time and it's a legit company. It's now called TuneIn but they still use radiotime.com.

Answer (score 0):

There's no malware. This is a consequence of bad redirection from your unblocker. If you disable it, the problem will go away.

> I am using one of those SmartDNS services to unblock content from other regions (Unblock-Us.com), but it couldn't be related to that, because I've set it up on my router (so it's enabled for all of my devices) and YouTube works just fine on any other device.

That doesn't prove anything. They could have cached different address for `youtube.com`.